# raweng FlipView can work for iOS 5 or not?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Greeting everyone.

I would like to upgrade my App from iOS 4 to iOS 5, 
and planning for my schedule.

(I cannot upgrade my x-code to iOS 5 sdk first, because I'm using for development.

In my apps, I used raweng's flip view for content display, 
I tried to access the API web site, but the URL is not longer valid:
https://github.com/raweng/FlipView

I'm not sure it's work for iOS 5 or not. 
Could you please advise me this API can work for iOS 5 or not?

Thank you so much.

Comment: this link is not working,"https://github.com/raweng/FlipView"

Comment: Actually you can have more than one copy of XCode installed by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works on iOS5, get my fork https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

due to some reason we need to put the https://github.com/raweng/FlipView down !

if you have any issues then you can drop me an email :)